# найти минимальное число, большее данного, такое что оно делиться на произведение своих цифр без остатка

Tags: c, логика

Перепробовал что мог , всё равно не проходит , может кто подсказать в чём проблема?или найти решение

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int x, s, d, g, f, j = 0;
    scanf("%d", &x);
    s = x / 100; //сотни
    g = x % 100;
    d = g / 10; // десятки
    f = x % 10; // еденицы 
    if ((s < 10) && (d == 0 && f == 0))
    {
        j = s;
        printf("%d", x);
        return(0);
    }
    if (s < 10 && (d < 10 && f < 10))
    {
        j = s * d * f;
    }
    if ((s < 10) && (d < 10 && f == 0))
    {
        j = s * d;
    }
    if ((s < 10) && (d == 0 && f < 10))
    {
        j = s * f;
    }
    if (s == 0 && d < 10 && f < 10)
    {
        j = d * f;
    }
    if (s == 0 && d < 10 && f == 0)
    {
        j = d;
    }
    if (x <= 10)
    {
        x = x + 1;
        printf("%d", x);
        return(0);
    }
    x = x + 1;
    while (x % j != 0) {
        x++;
    }
    printf("%d", x);
}
```

Comment: Вам надо написать функцию, которая возвращает поизведение цифр числа и использовать ее в цикле подбора числа. (только не забудьте проверять, что это произведение не равно 0)

Comment: Почему в последнем цикле `x` меняется а `j` нет? Вы добавили единичку к `x`, его цифры стали другими, значит и их произведение изменилось.

Comment: именно так , не могу понять как сделать что бы после окончания цикла менялись значения j

Comment: Если вам нужно вычислить новое значение `j`, надо его вычислить. И не по окончании цикла, а в каждой итерации цикла. Для каждого `x` должен быть вычислен свой `j`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
int main() {
    int x;
    scanf("%d", &x);

    for (++x;;x++) {
        int n = x, p = 1;

        while (n) {
            p *= n % 10;
            n /= 10;
            }

        if (p == 0 || x % p) continue;

        printf("%d\n", x);
        break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Не получается , при некоторых значениях выдаёт тоже самое число , хотя должно прибавлять , при x < 10 , при x =111 и т д

Comment: Тогда уж пишите `(!p || x % p)`. Я к тому что приведение `int` -> `bool` - плохая идея. Не надо ею пользоваться. Люди читают выражение `x % p` как "икс делится на пэ", а оно значит обратное. Займём в интернете несколько символов: `(p == 0 || x % p != 0)`.

Comment: @MelanholExis Ну если *строго*, то очевидно же, что надо написать дополнительный `++x`. Неужели до этого невозможно додуматься самостоятельно? Хорошо, добавил в ответ...